# Facebook Profile Picture not loading using Picasso on some devices (Android)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, picasso, image-loading

I use the following code to load user profile pictures from Facebook.

```
final String fbDpURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbId + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
Picasso.with(context).load(fbDpURL).placeholder(R.drawable.default_person).transform(new RoundedTransformation(100, 1)).into(holder.iv_fbPic);
```

Where `fbId` is the Facebook user-id acquired after Facebook login. On some devices like the Moto G, I have noticed that the images are not being loaded. I'm already using `"https://"` in my url as mentioned in various answers on questions with similar problems. But this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: for test case use `Glide ` https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I would be interested in knowing the cause. I am aware of other Image Downloading frameworks. This anomaly has been identified recently, and I am sure there must be a quick-fix. Thanks

Comment: i guess problem for `RoundedTransformation` .Comment `transform(new RoundedTransformation(100, 1))` for test case

Comment: Nope, The same issue is there without the transform. I also registered Picasso interfaces for onBitmap loaded and all. I noticed, that none of the callBack interfaces from Picasso are being called. Seems like an issue with Picasso.